# how to get particular user position based on score in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, ranking, nosql

**Scenario:**
Total number of users: 1,000,000
Get top 50 user position and score.
Also current user position and score.

**My Table structure:**

id | username | score | category

**My logic:**

Set GSI based on score 
Query with ScanIndexForward is "false" and set limit 50.
it shows top 50 users.

how to get current user positon and score?

Comment: What do you mean by current user position and score?

Comment: like rank, the current user rank  among the 100000 users

Comment: Still not clear. Are you ranking the user based on score? What do you mean by current user position in this context? I think you are not mentioning the full description of the model or requirement

Comment: user "A"  login and watch the scoreboard. scoreboard list top 50 users based on score, and also display the user "A" is like 1000th position and its score is "20"

Comment: You have to get the current user separately if it is not already available on top 50... You can't combine in one database call.

Comment: **step1:** find top 50 users based on score with the help of GSI "TOPSCORE" limit 50 -  **step 2:** find user "A" score (output: "20") - **step 3:**    condition score > user "A" score (i.e, 20) with GSI  "TOPSCORE".     is any other efficient way?

Comment: No other way ..